# How to replace <br> and </br> with a new line on discord.js bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm setting up my discord bot and on one of the commands, when the bot replies, it has some `<br>` and `</br>` in the message and I want to remove them for a new line.

I've tried `.replace(/<br>/g, "\n"));` and that didn't work.

```
case "roblox":
    args.length < 1 ? message.channel.send("Please enter an roblox user.") : message.channel.send(await getAPI("api here" + args).replace(/<br>/g, "\n"));
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/<\/?br\s?\/?>/g
```

Replaces `<br>` and `</br>` (invalid), as well as `<br/>` and `<br />`.

Comment: tried this and it didnt work add my discord strat#4857

Answer (score 0):

Try this more broader regex

```
.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n"));
```

you can use `/<br[^>]*>/gi` which will match anything between the br and slash if you have for example `<br class="hello" />`

Comment: tried this and it didnt work add my discord strat#4857